# CUDAGRIND - MEMORY TRANSACTION CHECKING FOR CUDA in windows

Tags: windows, cuda

I am using cuda c in visual studio. for checking the memory I use cuda-memccheck . while going through some sites I found that cudagrind of valgrind provides much more details of the error of memory.and further this is my misunderstanding or what I found it can be only used in linux system. Am I right?? or can cudagrind be applied in windows to check the memory error???

Comment: cudagrind is an extension to valgrind. valgrind is Linux only, so it follows that cudagrind can't be used on Windows platforms